# AVAudioSession use AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone and AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording

Tags: iphone, ios6, avaudiosession

Hi guys I'm doing an enterprise app to detect when an iOS device as a failing microphone or speaker.

I need to use the secondary microphone (the one used when recording video) and the only way I found it was using AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording but I also need to use lower speaker and I am using AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone, but the problem is that when I use AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording the audio always goes thru the speaker and not the default earpiece.

here is my code

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

BOOL success;
NSError* error;

success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);

success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error on output audio port: %@",error);

success = [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording error:&error];
if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting mode: %@",error);
```

thanks guys

Comment: I have the same issue, have you resolved that?

Comment: I could not find a way to do it, probably with private apis can be done, but I didn't research on that.